# How do I apply an auto_size_text inside a bottomNavigationBar text in flutter

Tags: flutter, tabbar, flutter-bottomnavigation

How can I apply the auto_size_text property, or something similar to the texts inside the bottomNavigationBar in flutter.

```
  body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          TabIndex(),
          TabPending(widget.selectedPageWithin),
          TabDebt(),
          TabFavor(),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: new TabBar(
        tabs: [
          Tab(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.today),
            text: 'Mi grilla',

          ),
          Tab(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.hourglass_full),
            text: 'Solicit.',
          ),
          Tab(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.indeterminate_check_box),
            text: 'Deuda',
          ),
          Tab(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.add_box),
            text: 'A favor',
          )
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using tab you can use a column . eg

```
Column(children:[
Icon(Icons.today),
AutosizeText('Hi mom')
]),
```